# how to send post to a class form a url?

Tags: php, web-services

I want to write a simple `PHP` code that will send data to a class in a URL.
I've written code, but it's only for sending data directly to the URL.
How to write this code?
The class name is 'sendmsg'.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://thxmain.cellmobilen.net:443/Charg/service/ChargingMobile';

$data = array(
 'username' => '?',
 'password' => '?',
 'domain' => '?',
 'channel' => '?',
 'mobilenum' => '?',
 'serviceId' => '?',
 'price' => '?',
 'trackingId' => '?'
);

$options = array(
   'http' => array(
       'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'content' => http_build_query($data)
   )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if ($result !== FALSE) {
 var_dump($result);
}else{
 print( "Code is wrong" );
}

?>
```

Comment: sorry but I don't get your question really? Does the code you post work? Do I understand you right that somewhere there exists a class that you wrote youself, which is called `sendmsg`? And instead of the post request you want to call the class?

Comment: I want to send the data to class sendmsg at this url. The problem with this code is that it doesn't send data to the class. Please help me to send data to class sendmsg.